# Parse error on input `_'

Tags: parsing, haskell

Line 7, at the _. I've no idea what might be the problem. Any tips?

```
term :: Parser Expr
term s1 = case factor s1 of
            Just (a, s2) -> case s2 of
                              '*':s3 -> case term s3 of
                                          Just (b, s4) -> Just (Mul a b, s4)
                                          Nothing      -> Just (a, s2)
                                _ -> Just (a, s2)
            Nothing      -> Nothing
```

I'm trying to parse a string into an Expr (selfmade datatype). I think this is how we're supposed to do it but i can't test it since i can't compile it properly. GHCI and Ghc wall gives me the same error. Parse error at that specific point.

My code is larger than this but this is the rellevant piece of code.

edit: Code posted here, sorry.

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a syntax problem. Haskell uses two-dimensional syntax, thus each part of the case statement should have same indentation.

So, to fix the error move line 7 two characters left

```
term :: Parser Expr
term s1 = case factor s1 of
            Just (a, s2) -> case s2 of
                              '*':s3 -> case term s3 of
                                          Just (b, s4) -> Just (Mul a b, s4)
                                          Nothing      -> Just (a, s2)
                              _ -> Just (a, s2)
            Nothing      -> Nothing
```

Comment: Ah i still get the same error though. And eventhough the _ letter now is located at the 31st character, it still says the parse error is at the 32nd.

Comment: Actually, it did solve my problem hehe, i had an almost identical piece of code below that one which i edited by mistake instead of this one. Thanks!